# Javascript: how to validate dates in format MM-DD-YYYY?

Tags: javascript, validation, date

I saw a potential answer here but that was for YYYY-MM-DD: [JavaScript date validation](http://paulschreiber.com/blog/2007/03/02/javascript-date-validation/)

I modified the code code above for MM-DD-YYYY like so but I still can't get it to work:

```
String.prototype.isValidDate = function() 
{
     var IsoDateRe = new RegExp("^([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4})$");
     var matches = IsoDateRe.exec(this);
     if (!matches) return false;
     var composedDate = new Date(matches[3], (matches[1] - 1), matches[2]);
     return ((composedDate.getMonth() == (matches[1] - 1)) &&
      (composedDate.getDate() == matches[2]) &&
      (composedDate.getFullYear() == matches[3]));
}
```

How can I get the above code to work for MM-DD-YYYY and better yet MM/DD/YYYY?

Thanks.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15764763/1709992

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format date to MM/dd/yyyy in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591854/format-date-to-mm-dd-yyyy-in-javascript)

Comment: or simply you can use this for validation https://www.npmjs.com/package/raysk-vali

Comment: See answers of duplicate in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177975/how-to-validate-date-with-format-mm-dd-yyyy-in-javascript

Answer (score 80):

```
function isValidDate(date)
{
    var matches = /^(\d{1,2})[-\/](\d{1,2})[-\/](\d{4})$/.exec(date);
    if (matches == null) return false;
    var d = matches[2];
    var m = matches[1] - 1;
    var y = matches[3];
    var composedDate = new Date(y, m, d);
    return composedDate.getDate() == d &&
            composedDate.getMonth() == m &&
            composedDate.getFullYear() == y;
}
console.log(isValidDate('10-12-1961'));
console.log(isValidDate('12/11/1961'));
console.log(isValidDate('02-11-1961'));
console.log(isValidDate('12/01/1961'));
console.log(isValidDate('13-11-1961'));
console.log(isValidDate('11-31-1961'));
console.log(isValidDate('11-31-1061'));
```

It works. (Tested with Firebug, hence the console.log().)

Comment: @ChristianVielma Really? Have you tried the code? On which browser?

Comment: Nop, you're right, just tested it again and it is good. Sorry about that!

Comment: It does fail though if you use only one digit for the month. For example, '1-31-2013' will fail. Also, one digit for the day '01-1-2013' or if you use two digits for the year '01-01-13'

Comment: use this regular expression to accept one digit day and month values.
/^(\d{1,2})[-\/](\d{1,2})[-\/](\d{4})$/

Comment: @AnilNamde edited my answer to accept 1 digit day or month. I won't edit it back as it might have its use (judging by comments above), but that's not what was asked originally...

Answer (score 13):

```
function isValidDate(date) {
        var valid = true;

        date = date.replace('/-/g', '');

        var month = parseInt(date.substring(0, 2),10);
        var day   = parseInt(date.substring(2, 4),10);
        var year  = parseInt(date.substring(4, 8),10);

        if(isNaN(month) || isNaN(day) || isNaN(year)) return false;

        if((month < 1) || (month > 12)) valid = false;
        else if((day < 1) || (day > 31)) valid = false;
        else if(((month == 4) || (month == 6) || (month == 9) || (month == 11)) && (day > 30)) valid = false;
        else if((month == 2) && (((year % 400) == 0) || ((year % 4) == 0)) && ((year % 100) != 0) && (day > 29)) valid = false;
        else if((month == 2) && ((year % 100) == 0) && (day > 29)) valid = false;
        else if((month == 2) && (day > 28)) valid = false;

    return valid;
}
```

This checks for valid days in each month and for valid leap year days.

Comment: FYI, you need to correct your second and fourth elseIf. #2 Remove (month ==7) because July does have 31 days. #4 Change ((year % 100) == 0) || (day > 28)) to ((year % 100) == 0) && (day > 28)). This specifies all three conditions must be met. Otherwise the func will return false if Day > 28 regardless if its a leap year or not. Anyway, you get a +1 because this helped me alot.

Comment: Fyi, for future readers, you MUST also apply the following to your code for the above to work correctly. Change date.replace seen above to "date.replace(/-/g, '')" to make sure it replaces all the hyphens, rather than just the first. Also, you will encounter a 1:1000000 design quirk in parseInt with your day variable if date.substring(2,4) is either '08' or '09. See the next link for details and a solution.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/191434

Comment: if I'm not wrong this should be written without ' .
date = date.replace(/-/g, '');
Otherwise it will look for a string like "/-/g".

Comment: and I'm 100% sure that your leap year code is bugged (it validates as true even a date like this 02-29-2001)

Comment: @sataniccrow now it is fixed

Comment: @VitalijZadneprovskij if i give input date as "abc" or "123" it gives true. I think this validation is not fully complete.

Answer (score 5):

How about validating dates in "ANY" date format?  I've been using the DateJS library and adding it to existing forms to ensure that I get valid dates & times formatted the way that I want.  The user can even enter things like "now" and "tomorrow" and it will be converted into a valid date.

Here's the dateJS library:
http://www.datejs.com/

and here's a jQuery tip that I wrote:
http://www.ssmedia.com/utilities/jquery/index.cfm/datejs.htm

Answer (score 4):

I use this regex for validating MM-DD-YYYY:

```
function isValidDate(subject){
  if (subject.match(/^(?:(0[1-9]|1[012])[\- \/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\- \/.](19|20)[0-9]{2})$/)){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

It will match only valid months and you can use / - or . as separators.

Comment: it will return 02/29/2011 as true but it should return it false

Comment: According to your function '02-29-2011' is a valid date and even '02-30-2011', '02-31-2011' are valid dates.

Answer (score 4):

This function will validate the date to see if it's correct or if it's in the proper format of: DD/MM/YYYY.

```
function isValidDate(date)
{
    var matches = /^(\d{2})[-\/](\d{2})[-\/](\d{4})$/.exec(date);
    if (matches == null) return false;
    var d = matches[1];
    var m = matches[2]-1;
    var y = matches[3];
    var composedDate = new Date(y, m, d);
    return composedDate.getDate() == d &&
           composedDate.getMonth() == m &&
           composedDate.getFullYear() == y;
}
console.log(isValidDate('10-12-1961'));
console.log(isValidDate('12/11/1961'));
console.log(isValidDate('02-11-1961'));
console.log(isValidDate('12/01/1961'));
console.log(isValidDate('13-11-1961'));
console.log(isValidDate('11-31-1961'));
console.log(isValidDate('11-31-1061'));
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for this task. It makes it *very easy* to parse dates and it also provides support to detect a an invalid date<sup>1</sup> in the correct format. For instance, consider [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/ygqgz/):

```
var formats = ['MM-DD-YYYY', 'MM/DD/YYYY']

moment('11/28/1981', formats).isValid()  // true
moment('2-29-2003', formats).isValid()   // false (not leap year)
moment('2-29-2004', formats).isValid()   // true  (leap year)
```

First `moment(.., formats)` is used to parse the input according to the localized format supplied. Then the `isValid` function is called on the resulting moment object so that we can actually tell if it is a *valid* date.

This can be used to trivially derive the isValidDate method:

```
String.prototype.isValidDate = function() {
    var formats = ['MM-DD-YYYY', 'MM/DD/YYYY'];
    return moment("" + this, formats).isValid();
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> As I can find scarce little commentary on the matter, I would only use moment.js for dates covered by the [Gregorian calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar). There may be plugins for other (including historical or scientific) calendars.

Answer (score 3):

what isn't working about it? here's a tested version:

```
String.prototype.isValidDate = function()   {

    const match = this.match(/^([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4})$/);
    if (!match || match.length !== 4) {
        return false
    }

    const test = new Date(match[3], match[1] - 1, match[2]);

    return (
        (test.getMonth() == match[1] - 1) &&
        (test.getDate() == match[2]) &&
        (test.getFullYear() == match[3])
    );
}

var date = '12/08/1984'; // Date() is 'Sat Dec 08 1984 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)'
alert(date.isValidDate() ); // true
```

Comment: what if no matches are found then new Date(match[3], match[1] - 1, match[2]); won't work -- update: fixed it

Answer (score 2):

Simple way to solve

```
var day = document.getElementById("DayTextBox").value;

var regExp = /^([1-9]|[1][012])\/|-([1-9]|[1][0-9]|[2][0-9]|[3][01])\/|-([1][6-9][0-9][0-9]|[2][0][01][0-9])$/;

return regExp.test(day);
```

Comment: According to your code '02-29-2011' is a valid date and even '02-30-2011', '02-31-2011' are valid dates.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify it somewhat by changing the first two lines of the function to this:

```
var matches = this.match(/^([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4})$/);
```

Or, just change the parameter to the RegExp constructor to be

```
^([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4})$
```

Answer (score 0):

pass this function to date with format //10-10-2012 and id of object.

```
function isValidDateFormat(date, id)
{
  var todayDate = new Date();
  var matches = /^(\d{2})[-\/](\d{2})[-\/](\d{4})$/.exec(date);

  if (matches == null)
  {
   if(date != '__-__-____')
    {
      alert('Please enter valid date');
    }
  }
  else
  {
    var day    = 31;
    var month  = 12;
    var b_date = date.split("-");
    if(b_date[0] <= day)
    {
      if(b_date[1] <= month)
      {
        if(b_date[2] >= 1900 && b_date[2] <= todayDate.getFullYear())
        {
          return true;
        }
        else
        {
          $("#"+id).val('');
          alert('Please enter valid Year'); 
        }         
      }
      else
      {
        $("#"+id).val('');
        alert('Please enter valid Month');    
      } 
    }
    else
    {
      alert('Please enter valid Day');
      $("#"+id).val('');  
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why jQuery is needed here?

Answer (score 0):

This is for validating the date string in formate dd.mm.yyyy It is easy to customize it. You just need to adjust the pos1 and pos2 in isValidDate().

var dtCh= ".";
    var minYear=1900;

```
function isInteger(s){
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++){   
        // Check that current character is number.
        var c = s.charAt(i);
        if (((c < "0") || (c > "9"))) return false;
    }
    // All characters are numbers.
    return true;
}

function stripCharsInBag(s, bag){
    var i;
    var returnString = "";
    // Search through string's characters one by one.
    // If character is not in bag, append to returnString.
    for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++){   
        var c = s.charAt(i);
        if (bag.indexOf(c) == -1) returnString += c;
    }
    return returnString;
}

function daysInFebruary (year){
    // February has 29 days in any year evenly divisible by four,
    // EXCEPT for centurial years which are not also divisible by 400.
    return (((year % 4 == 0) && ( (!(year % 100 == 0)) || (year % 400 == 0))) ? 29 : 28 );
}
function DaysArray(n) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        this[i] = 31;
        if (i==4 || i==6 || i==9 || i==11) {
            this[i] = 30;
        }
        if (i==2) {
            this[i] = 29;
        }
   } 
   return this;
}

function isValidDate(dtStr){
    var daysInMonth = DaysArray(12);
    var pos1=dtStr.indexOf(dtCh);
    var pos2=dtStr.indexOf(dtCh,pos1+1);
    var strDay=dtStr.substring(0,pos1);
    var strMonth=dtStr.substring(pos1+1,pos2);
    var strYear=dtStr.substring(pos2+1);
    strYr=strYear;
    if (strDay.charAt(0)=="0" && strDay.length>1) 
        strDay=strDay.substring(1);
    if (strMonth.charAt(0)=="0" && strMonth.length>1) 
        strMonth=strMonth.substring(1);
    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        if (strYr.charAt(0)=="0" && strYr.length>1) 
            strYr=strYr.substring(1);
    }
    month=parseInt(strMonth);
    day=parseInt(strDay);
    year=parseInt(strYr);
    if (pos1==-1 || pos2==-1){
        alert("The date format should be : dd.mm.yyyy");
        return false;
    }
    if (strMonth.length<1 || month<1 || month>12){
        alert("Please enter a valid month");
        return false;
    }
    if (strDay.length<1 || day<1 || day>31 || (month==2 && day>daysInFebruary(year)) || day > daysInMonth[month]){
        alert("Please enter a valid day");
        return false;
    }
    if (strYear.length != 4 || year==0 || year<minYear){
        alert("Please enter a valid 4 digit year after "+minYear);
        return false;
    }
    if (dtStr.indexOf(dtCh,pos2+1)!=-1 || isInteger(stripCharsInBag(dtStr, dtCh))==false){
        alert("Please enter a valid date");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (document.getElementById('expiryDay').value != test(match("/^([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})$/"))){
     alert("Enter the date in two digit month flowed by two digits year \n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>  

<title></title>  
 <script>
     function dateCheck(inputText) {
         debugger;

         var dateFormat = /^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-]\d{4}$/;

         var flag = 1;

         if (inputText.value.match(dateFormat)) {
             document.myForm.dateInput.focus();

             var inputFormat1 = inputText.value.split('/');
             var inputFormat2 = inputText.value.split('-');
             linputFormat1 = inputFormat1.length;
             linputFormat2 = inputFormat2.length;

             if (linputFormat1 > 1) {
                 var pdate = inputText.value.split('/');
             }
             else if (linputFormat2 > 1) {
                 var pdate = inputText.value.split('-');
             }
             var date = parseInt(pdate[0]);
             var month = parseInt(pdate[1]);
             var year = parseInt(pdate[2]);

             var ListofDays = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
             if (month == 1 || month > 2) {
                 if (date > ListofDays[month - 1]) {
                     alert("Invalid date format!");
                     return false;
                 }
             }

             if (month == 2) {
                 var leapYear = false;

                 if ((!(year % 4) && year % 100) || !(year % 400)) {
                     leapYear = true;

                 }
                 if ((leapYear == false) && (date >= 29)) {
                     alert("Invalid date format!");
                     return false;
                 }
                 if ((leapYear == true) && (date > 29)) {
                     alert("Invalid date format!");
                     return false;
                 }
             }
             if (flag == 1) {
                 alert("Valid Date");
             }
         }
         else {
             alert("Invalid date format!");
             document.myForm.dateInput.focus();
             return false;
         }
     }
     function restrictCharacters(evt) {

         evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
         var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
         if (((charCode >= '48') && (charCode <= '57')) || (charCode == '47')) {
             return true;
         }
         else {
             return false;
         }
     }


 </script>   
</head>



<body>  
    <div>  
        <form name="myForm" action="#">   
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Enter Date</td>
                    <td><input type="text" onkeypress="return restrictCharacters(event);" name="dateInput"/></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><span id="span2"></span></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="dateCheck(document.myForm.dateInput)"  /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>  
    </div>   
</body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find in the below code which enables to perform the date validation for any of the supplied format or based on user locale to validate start/from and end/to dates. There could be some better approaches but have come up with this. Have tested it for the formats like: MM/dd/yyyy, dd/MM/yyyy, yyyy-MM-dd, yyyy.MM.dd, yyyy/MM/dd and dd-MM-yyyy.

**Note supplied date format and date string go hand in hand.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate(format) {

    if(isAfterCurrentDate(document.getElementById('start').value, format)) {
        alert('Date is after the current date.');
    } else {
        alert('Date is not after the current date.');
    }
    if(isBeforeCurrentDate(document.getElementById('start').value, format)) {
        alert('Date is before current date.');
    } else {
        alert('Date is not before current date.');
    }
    if(isCurrentDate(document.getElementById('start').value, format)) {
        alert('Date is current date.');
    } else {
        alert('Date is not a current date.');
    }
    if (isBefore(document.getElementById('start').value, document.getElementById('end').value, format)) {
        alert('Start/Effective Date cannot be greater than End/Expiration Date');
    } else {
        alert('Valid dates...');
    }
    if (isAfter(document.getElementById('start').value, document.getElementById('end').value, format)) {
        alert('End/Expiration Date cannot be less than Start/Effective Date');
    } else {
        alert('Valid dates...');
    }
    if (isEquals(document.getElementById('start').value, document.getElementById('end').value, format)) {
        alert('Dates are equals...');
    } else {
        alert('Dates are not equals...');
    }
    if (isDate(document.getElementById('start').value, format)) {
        alert('Is valid date...');
    } else {
        alert('Is invalid date...');
    }
}

/**
 * This method gets the year index from the supplied format
 */
function getYearIndex(format) {

    var tokens = splitDateFormat(format);

    if (tokens[0] === 'YYYY'
            || tokens[0] === 'yyyy') {
        return 0;
    } else if (tokens[1]=== 'YYYY'
            || tokens[1] === 'yyyy') {
        return 1;
    } else if (tokens[2] === 'YYYY'
            || tokens[2] === 'yyyy') {
        return 2;
    }
    // Returning the default value as -1
    return -1;
}

/**
 * This method returns the year string located at the supplied index
 */
function getYear(date, index) {

    var tokens = splitDateFormat(date);
    return tokens[index];
}

/**
 * This method gets the month index from the supplied format
 */
function getMonthIndex(format) {

    var tokens = splitDateFormat(format);

    if (tokens[0] === 'MM'
            || tokens[0] === 'mm') {
        return 0;
    } else if (tokens[1] === 'MM'
            || tokens[1] === 'mm') {
        return 1;
    } else if (tokens[2] === 'MM'
            || tokens[2] === 'mm') {
        return 2;
    }
    // Returning the default value as -1
    return -1;
}

/**
 * This method returns the month string located at the supplied index
 */
function getMonth(date, index) {

    var tokens = splitDateFormat(date);
    return tokens[index];
}

/**
 * This method gets the date index from the supplied format
 */
function getDateIndex(format) {

    var tokens = splitDateFormat(format);

    if (tokens[0] === 'DD'
            || tokens[0] === 'dd') {
        return 0;
    } else if (tokens[1] === 'DD'
            || tokens[1] === 'dd') {
        return 1;
    } else if (tokens[2] === 'DD'
            || tokens[2] === 'dd') {
        return 2;
    }
    // Returning the default value as -1
    return -1;
}

/**
 * This method returns the date string located at the supplied index
 */
function getDate(date, index) {

    var tokens = splitDateFormat(date);
    return tokens[index];
}

/**
 * This method returns true if date1 is before date2 else return false
 */
function isBefore(date1, date2, format) {
    // Validating if date1 date is greater than the date2 date
    if (new Date(getYear(date1, getYearIndex(format)), 
            getMonth(date1, getMonthIndex(format)) - 1, 
            getDate(date1, getDateIndex(format))).getTime()
        > new Date(getYear(date2, getYearIndex(format)), 
            getMonth(date2, getMonthIndex(format)) - 1, 
            getDate(date2, getDateIndex(format))).getTime()) {
        return true;
    } 
    return false;                
}

/**
 * This method returns true if date1 is after date2 else return false
 */
function isAfter(date1, date2, format) {
    // Validating if date2 date is less than the date1 date
    if (new Date(getYear(date2, getYearIndex(format)), 
            getMonth(date2, getMonthIndex(format)) - 1, 
            getDate(date2, getDateIndex(format))).getTime()
        < new Date(getYear(date1, getYearIndex(format)), 
            getMonth(date1, getMonthIndex(format)) - 1, 
            getDate(date1, getDateIndex(format))).getTime()
        ) {
        return true;
    } 
    return false;                
}

/**
 * This method returns true if date1 is equals to date2 else return false
 */
function isEquals(date1, date2, format) {
    // Validating if date1 date is equals to the date2 date
    if (new Date(getYear(date1, getYearIndex(format)), 
            getMonth(date1, getMonthIndex(format)) - 1, 
            getDate(date1, getDateIndex(format))).getTime()
        === new Date(getYear(date2, getYearIndex(format)), 
            getMonth(date2, getMonthIndex(format)) - 1, 
            getDate(date2, getDateIndex(format))).getTime()) {
        return true;
    } 
    return false;
}

/**
 * This method validates and returns true if the supplied date is 
 * equals to the current date.
 */
function isCurrentDate(date, format) {
    // Validating if the supplied date is the current date
    if (new Date(getYear(date, getYearIndex(format)), 
            getMonth(date, getMonthIndex(format)) - 1, 
            getDate(date, getDateIndex(format))).getTime()
        === new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 
                new Date().getMonth(), 
                new Date().getDate()).getTime()) {
        return true;
    } 
    return false;                
}

/**
 * This method validates and returns true if the supplied date value 
 * is before the current date.
 */
function isBeforeCurrentDate(date, format) {
    // Validating if the supplied date is before the current date
    if (new Date(getYear(date, getYearIndex(format)), 
            getMonth(date, getMonthIndex(format)) - 1, 
            getDate(date, getDateIndex(format))).getTime()
        < new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 
                new Date().getMonth(), 
                new Date().getDate()).getTime()) {
        return true;
    } 
    return false;                
}

/**
 * This method validates and returns true if the supplied date value 
 * is after the current date.
 */
function isAfterCurrentDate(date, format) {
    // Validating if the supplied date is before the current date
    if (new Date(getYear(date, getYearIndex(format)), 
            getMonth(date, getMonthIndex(format)) - 1, 
            getDate(date, getDateIndex(format))).getTime()
        > new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),
                new Date().getMonth(), 
                new Date().getDate()).getTime()) {
        return true;
    } 
    return false;                
}

/**
 * This method splits the supplied date OR format based 
 * on non alpha numeric characters in the supplied string.
 */
function splitDateFormat(dateFormat) {
    // Spliting the supplied string based on non characters
    return dateFormat.split(/\W/);
}

/*
 * This method validates if the supplied value is a valid date.
 */
function isDate(date, format) {                
    // Validating if the supplied date string is valid and not a NaN (Not a Number)
    if (!isNaN(new Date(getYear(date, getYearIndex(format)), 
            getMonth(date, getMonthIndex(format)) - 1, 
            getDate(date, getDateIndex(format))))) {                    
        return true;
    } 
    return false;                                      
}
```

> Below is the HTML snippet

```
    <input type="text" name="start" id="start" size="10" value="05/31/2016" />
<br/> 
<input type="text" name="end" id="end" size="10" value="04/28/2016" />
<br/>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="javascript:validate('MM/dd/yyyy');" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If your date needs to match DD.MM.YYYY and use AngularJS, use the following code:

```
$scope.validDate = function(value){
            var matches = /^(\d{1,2})[.](\d{1,2})[.](\d{4})$/.exec(value);
            if (matches == null) return false;
            var d = matches[1];
            var m = matches[2] - 1;
            var y = matches[3];
            var composedDate = new Date(y, m, d);
            return composedDate.getDate() == d &&
                composedDate.getMonth() == m &&
                composedDate.getFullYear() == y;
        };
            console.log($scope.validDate('22.04.2001'));
            console.log($scope.validDate('03.10.2001'));
            console.log($scope.validDate('30.02.2001'));
            console.log($scope.validDate('23.09.2016'));
            console.log($scope.validDate('29.02.2016'));
            console.log($scope.validDate('31.02.2016'));
```

More about the scope object can be found [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope). Without AngularJS, simply change the first line to:

```
ValidDate = new function(value) {
```

And call it using:

```
var MyDate= ValidDate('29.09.2016');
```

Comment: This isn't an answer to the Original question but I see that the question has changed to some kind of a knowledge base article for JS and dates. Could you add some info about the `$scope` object, as far as I know it is not a standard object and would create an object reference error.

Comment: I've used this solution in my AngularJs Project.
$Scope [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) is an object that refers to the application model. 
If you paste this code into a project without AngularJs, you have to remove the $scope object to get it work.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, now the answer makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

DateFormat = DD.MM.YYYY or D.M.YYYY

```
function dateValidate(val){ 
var dateStr = val.split('.'); 
  var date = new Date(dateStr[2], dateStr[1]-1, dateStr[0]); 
  if(date.getDate() == dateStr[0] && date.getMonth()+1 == dateStr[1] && date.getFullYear() == dateStr[2])
  { return date; }
  else{ return 'NotValid';} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function validateDate(dates){
    re = /^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})$/;     
    var days=new Array(31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31);

            if(regs = dates.match(re)) {
                    // day value between 1 and 31
                    if(regs[1] < 1 || regs[1] > 31) {                    
                      return false;
                    }
                    // month value between 1 and 12
                    if(regs[2] < 1 || regs[2] > 12) {                         
                      return false;
                    }

                    var maxday=days[regs[2]-1];

                    if(regs[2]==2){
                        if(regs[3]%4==0){
                            maxday=maxday+1;                                
                        }
                    }

                    if(regs[1]>maxday){
                        return false;
                    }

                    return true;
              }else{
                  return false;
              }                   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short and fast.

```js
function dateValid(date) {
  var match = date.match(/^(\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d{4})$/) || [];
  var m = (match[1] | 0) - 1;
  var d = match[2] | 0;
  var y = match[3] | 0;
  return !(
      m < 0 ||                     // Before January
      m > 11 ||                    // After December
      d < 1 ||                     // Before the 1st of the month
      d - 30 > (2773 >> m & 1) ||  // After the 30th or 31st of the month using bitmap
      m == 1 && d - 28 >           // After the 28th or 29th of February depending on leap year
          (!(y % 4) && y % 100 || !(y % 400)));
}

console.log('02-29-2000', dateValid('02-29-2000'));
console.log('02-29-2001', dateValid('02-29-2001'));
console.log('12-31-1970', dateValid('12-31-1970'));
console.log('Hello', dateValid('Hello'));
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it - for example, what's that part with `2741` about?

Comment: @NicoHaase added some code comments. 2741 is a bitmap where 1 means a month has 31 days, 0 means otherwise.

Comment: @AdamLeggett Replacing `(!(y % 4) && y % 100 || !(y % 400)))` with `!(y%4 || (!(y%100) && y%400)) )`  fixes a bug revealed by testing with non millennial leap years - the `y % 100` expression is not being converted to a boolean, so it doesn't get coerced to `1` in the numerical comparison.

Answer (score 0):

German Variant, but could be adapted to Iso

```
export function isLeapYear(year) {
  return (
    year % 4 === 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 1000 === 0 || year % 400 === 0)
  )
}

export function isValidGermanDate(germanDate) {
  if (
    !germanDate ||
    germanDate.length < 5 ||
    germanDate.split('.').length < 3
  ) {
    return false
  }

  const day = parseInt(germanDate.split('.')[0])
  const month = parseInt(germanDate.split('.')[1])
  const year = parseInt(germanDate.split('.')[2])

  if (isNaN(month) || isNaN(day) || isNaN(year)) {
    return false
  }

  if (month < 1 || month > 12) {
    return false
  }

  if (day < 1 || day > 31) {
    return false
  }

  if ((month === 4 || month === 6 || month === 9 || month === 11) && day > 30) {
    return false
  }

  if (isLeapYear(year)) {
    if (month === 2 && day > 29) {
      return false
    }
  } else {
    if (month === 2 && day > 28) {
      return false
    }
  }

  return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on "Short and Fast" above by @Adam Leggett, as cases like "02/30/2020" return `true` when it should be `false`. I really dig the bitmap though...

For a  MM/DD/YYYY date format validation:

```
const dateValid = (date) => {
  const isLeapYear = (yearNum) => {
    return ((yearNum % 100 === 0) ? (yearNum % 400 === 0) : (yearNum % 4 === 0))?
      1:
      0;
  }
  const match = date.match(/^(\d\d)\/(\d\d)\/(\d{4})$/) || [];
  const month = (match[1] | 0) - 1;
  const day = match[2] | 0;
  const year = match[3] | 0;

const dateEval=!( month < 0 ||                     // Before January
      month > 11 ||                    // After December
      day < 1 ||                     // Before the 1st of the month
      day - 30 > (2773 >> month & 1) ||
      month === 1 && day - 28 > isLeapYear(year) 
      // Day is 28 or 29, month is 02, year is leap year ==> true
      );

return `\nDate: ${date}\n\n     
  Valid Date?: ${dateEval}\n
  =======================================`
}

console.log(dateValid('02/28/2020')) // true
console.log(dateValid('02/29/2020')) // true
console.log(dateValid('02/30/2020')) // false
console.log(dateValid('01/31/2020')) // true
console.log(dateValid('01/31/2000')) // true
console.log(dateValid('04/31/2020')) // false
console.log(dateValid('04/31/2000')) // false
console.log(dateValid('04/30/2020')) // true
console.log(dateValid('01/32/2020')) // false
console.log(dateValid('02/28/2021')) // true
console.log(dateValid('02/29/2021')) // false
console.log(dateValid('02/30/2021')) // false
console.log(dateValid('02/28/2000')) // true
console.log(dateValid('02/29/2000')) // true
console.log(dateValid('02/30/2000')) // false
console.log(dateValid('02/28/2001')) // true
console.log(dateValid('02/29/2001')) // false
console.log(dateValid('02/30/2001')) // false
```

For a  MM-DD-YYYY date format validation: Replace `\/` in the pattern for `match` by `-`.

Answer (score -2):

```
<script language = "Javascript">
// Declaring valid date character, minimum year and maximum year
var dtCh= "/";
var minYear=1900;
var maxYear=2100;

function isInteger(s){
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++){   
        // Check that current character is number.
        var c = s.charAt(i);
        if (((c < "0") || (c > "9"))) return false;
    }
    // All characters are numbers.
    return true;
}

function stripCharsInBag(s, bag){
    var i;
    var returnString = "";
    // Search through string's characters one by one.
    // If character is not in bag, append to returnString.
    for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++){   
        var c = s.charAt(i);
        if (bag.indexOf(c) == -1) returnString += c;
    }
    return returnString;
}

function daysInFebruary (year){
    // February has 29 days in any year evenly divisible by four,
    // EXCEPT for centurial years which are not also divisible by 400.
    return (((year % 4 == 0) && ( (!(year % 100 == 0)) || (year % 400 == 0))) ? 29 : 28 );
}
function DaysArray(n) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        this[i] = 31
        if (i==4 || i==6 || i==9 || i==11) {this[i] = 30}
        if (i==2) {this[i] = 29}
   } 
   return this
}

function isDate(dtStr){
    var daysInMonth = DaysArray(12)
    var pos1=dtStr.indexOf(dtCh)
    var pos2=dtStr.indexOf(dtCh,pos1+1)
    var strDay=dtStr.substring(0,pos1)
    var strMonth=dtStr.substring(pos1+1,pos2)
    var strYear=dtStr.substring(pos2+1)
    strYr=strYear
    if (strDay.charAt(0)=="0" && strDay.length>1) strDay=strDay.substring(1)
    if (strMonth.charAt(0)=="0" && strMonth.length>1) strMonth=strMonth.substring(1)
    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        if (strYr.charAt(0)=="0" && strYr.length>1) strYr=strYr.substring(1)
    }
    month=parseInt(strMonth)
    day=parseInt(strDay)
    year=parseInt(strYr)
    if (pos1==-1 || pos2==-1){
        alert("The date format should be : dd/mm/yyyy")
        return false
    }
    if (strMonth.length<1 || month<1 || month>12){
        alert("Please enter a valid month")
        return false
    }
    if (strDay.length<1 || day<1 || day>31 || (month==2 && day>daysInFebruary(year)) || day > daysInMonth[month]){
        alert("Please enter a valid day")
        return false
    }
    if (strYear.length != 4 || year==0 || year<minYear || year>maxYear){
        alert("Please enter a valid 4 digit year between "+minYear+" and "+maxYear)
        return false
    }
    if (dtStr.indexOf(dtCh,pos2+1)!=-1 || isInteger(stripCharsInBag(dtStr, dtCh))==false){
        alert("Please enter a valid date")
        return false
    }
return true
}

function ValidateForm(){
    var dt=document.frmSample.txtDateenter code here
    if (isDate(dt.value)==false){
        dt.focus()
        return false
    }
    return true
 }

</script>
```