# how to check if from - to input fields for dates is correct using javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, date

i need to check if the user has inputted the correct from - to values for date on my form

for example: (dd/mm/yyyy)

WRONG:

```
From: 20/12/2012 - To: 11/12/2012
```

CORRECT:

```
From: 20/12/2012 - To: 30/12/2012
```

i need to check the values from the "from" and "to" input fields, so that i can pass the the value to my ajax script, is there anyway to achieve this result using javascript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6177975/544198

Comment: i need it to be in dd/mm/yyyy format not mm/dd/yyyy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF the dates are properly formatted

```
var BegDT = new Date(st1);
var EndDT = new Date(st2);
```

You can now subtract BegDT from EndDt and give an error if you don't get a positive number