# Validate Date input with Javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, date

I have a input field date in my form and would like to add Javascript validation to ensure that its always greater than today's date. I tried the following but the function doesnt seem to be called when the user clicks on the input field and makes a change.

```
<input type="text" name="InsertRecordGuestOrders_Delivery_date" id="InsertRecordGuestOrders_Delivery_date" value=""/>

<script type="text/javascript">

function validateDate()
{
var del_date = document.getElementById('InsertRecordGuestOrders_Delivery_date').value;

if (Date.parse(del_date) < Date.now()) {
    document.getElementById('InsertRecordGuestOrders_Delivery_date').value = '';
    alert("Delivery date has to be later than today");
    }
}

document.getElementById('InsertRecordGuestOrders_Delivery_date').onChange = validateDate();

</script>
```

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use document.getElementById('...').onChange = validateDate;

Comment: Tamil -Thanks for your quick response! I appreciate it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate date with format "mm/dd/yyyy" in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177975/how-to-validate-date-with-format-mm-dd-yyyy-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
document.getElementById('InsertRecordGuestOrders_Delivery_date').onChange = validateDate();
```

Should be:

```
document.getElementById('InsertRecordGuestOrders_Delivery_date').onchange = validateDate;
```

Notice the parentheses are gone. If you invoke it immediately, you're assigning the return value of `validateDate()` as the onchange handler. You want to assign the function itself as the handler, not the return value of the function.

In addition, it should be `onchange`, not `onChange`.

Comment: By the way, good catch on the "onchange". I tried it out in JsFiddle and it didnt work until I changed "onChange" -> "onchange". Appreciate the help! Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

You want to assign the `validateDate` function to the `onchange` property, not execute the function and assign its return value. Change this:

```
document.getElementById('...').onChange = validateDate();
```

to this:

```
document.getElementById('...').onChange = validateDate;
```