# Javascript: is there a shorter way to validate a date with regex? I want to allow m/d/yyyy as well as mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, date

My goal is to validate a user-entered date in javascript.

I am basing my code on https://stackoverflow.com/a/6178341/3255963, but that code was designed to only validate mm/dd/yyyy.

```
if(!/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/.test(dateString))
    return false;
```

I want to also allow users to enter m/d/yyyy (in other words no leading zeros).

It appears the following works but I was wondering if there is a way to do this with regex in one line.

```
if(
    !/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/.test(dateString) && 
    !/^\d{1}\/\d{1}\/\d{4}$/.test(dateString) &&
    !/^\d{1}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/.test(dateString) &&
    !/^\d{2}\/\d{1}\/\d{4}$/.test(dateString)
  )
  return false;
```

PS Another portion of the linked script verifies other aspects of the input, but I'm not modifying that part.

Comment: Please don't use a regex. Do you really want to accept `31/31/2014` as a valid date? Use a full date parser.

Comment: No need for regex - split the string on "/", then cast each element to `Number` and check that it's within a valid range.

Comment: Another part of the linked script deals with other aspects of the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify minimum and the maximum number of characters to be matched, like this

```
if(!/^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/.test(dateString))
```

**Note:** As [@Matt suggested in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188370/javascript-is-there-a-shorter-way-to-validate-a-date-with-regex-i-want-to-allo/22188384#comment33680744_22188370), using RegEx to validate date strings, is not a foolproof way.

Comment: Another part of the linked script validates other aspects. Is that full script not fullproof?

Comment: @CarbonandH20 If that parses the date string and validates it, then that should be fine.