# NaN error in Javascript

Tags: javascript

When I tab, the result putted in the textbox was NaN. While in my computer at home, it outputs a number. Please help.

```
function ageCount() {
  var date1 = new Date();
  var dob = document.getElementById("dob").value;
  var date2 = new Date(dob);
  var pattern = /^\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}$/;

  if (pattern.test(dob)) {
    var y1 = date1.getFullYear();
    //getting current year            
    var y2 = date2.getFullYear();
    //getting dob year            
    var age = y1 - y2;
    //calculating age                       
    document.getElementById("ageId").value = age;
    document.getElementById("ageId").focus ();
    return true;
  } else {
    alert("Invalid date format. Please Input in (dd/mm/yyyy) format!");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you do any debugging? For instance, `alert(date1); alert(date2);`?

Comment: What is the value of `dob` which causes the problem? Try stepping through your code in a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass an invalid date string to `Date`, you get an invalid Date.

```
(new Date("9999-99-99"))
```

If you call `getFullYear` on an invalid Date, you get `NaN`.

If you try to perform any arithmetic operations on `NaN`, you get `Nan`.

So, your problem is that you tabbed out of you input box and it was empty and this is what was passed to `Date` in your line:

```
var date2 = new Date(dob);
```

You should improve your `pattern` to eliminate any invalid date.

Answer (score 0):

If you really do search for `dd/mm/yyyy` date format,
then your pattern should be

`/^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/`

---

**Notice** : You're not actually calculating age but the difference between year of birth and current year.
If one's birthday occurs after current date, it will one year wrong.
You could look at [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6178341/3702797) for a good starting point on building this calculator.