# Javascript date looks wrong when changing the month

Tags: javascript

My eyes must be deceiving me, but when I call `setMonth(1)` shouldn't the date of that date object be February? (Today is March 30, 2016)

```
x = new Date();
y = new Date();
x.setMonth(1);

document.write(x.toString() + '<br>' + y.toString());
```

Results in:

[image]

Comment: Adam -- this code will only fail today (of all days) Instead can you please update your post to say that today is March 30, 2016 and then take a screenshot of the results.

Comment: If you mouse over the fuzzy dates, you can see the exact time the post was made.

Comment: These two topics about javascript date validation might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177975/how-to-validate-date-with-format-mm-dd-yyyy-in-javascript and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353684/detecting-an-invalid-date-date-instance-in-javascript?lq=1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no February 30, 2016

So therefore the date processor correctly changes the date to March 1, 2016

Comment: Just looking at [the spec for this](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-makeday) _"7. Find a value t such that..."_ - that's rather vague :)

Comment: Hmmm? What do you mean @JamesThorpe ?

Comment: Doesn't specify how to go about finding that value - it's usually quite specific about algorithms like this - just leaves it completely up to the implementation.  Just seemed out of place, especially when the next step is then very specific: _"Return Day(t) + dt − 1"_.