# regular expression validation of Date of Birth of range 1977 to 1999

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

How to Validate of Date of birth of range 1977 to 1999 in javascript enter `code here` DOB

```js
function validate() {
  var dob = document.getElementById('txtDOB').value;

  var pattern = /^()$/;

  if (dob == null || dob == "" || !pattern.test(dob)) {

    alert('Invalid date of birth');
    return false;
  } else {
    alert('valid');
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtDOB" />
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="validate()" />
```

Comment: What are the valid formats for DOB? `DD-MM-YYYY`?

Comment: How about changing string to int then compare the ints?

Comment: my date format is (dd/mm/yyyy) and datatype is date

Comment: You can use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23405144/427146) just change the year range over there! Also note that it is mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: If there's a fixed format of DOB like YYYY/MM/DD, split string by '/' and then check if year falls in given range.

Comment: Date validation is not direct in JS, there can be invalid dates like Feb-30 that regex can accept. This also works with `Date` constructor which returns march 1. So to validate date correctly custom function is recommended.

Comment: please help my friend. i want to check a year between 1977 to 1999

Answer (score 0):

## CHECK YEAR + VALID DATE

```js
function validate() {
  var date = new Date(document.getElementById('txtDOB').value), date = date ? date.getFullYear() : false;

  if (date && date >= 1977 && date <= 1999) {
    alert('valid');
    return true;
  } else {
    alert('Invalid date of birth');
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtDOB" />
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="validate()" />
```

## JUST CHECK YEAR (no check date valid):

```js
function validate() {
  var date = document.getElementById('txtDOB').value, date = date.match(/\d{4}/);

  if (date && date[0] >= 1977 && date[0] <= 1999) {
    alert('valid');
    return true;
  } else {
    alert('Invalid date of birth');
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtDOB" />
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="validate()" />
```

## ONLY FOR YOUR FORMAT (dd-mm-yyyy):

```js
function validate()
{
  var
    date      = document.getElementById('txtDOB').value,
    year      = date.match(/\d{4}/),
    extract   = date.replace(year,'').match(/(\d+)/g)
  ;

  if(date && year && year[0] >= 1977 && year[0] <= 1999 && new Date(extract[1]+'/'+extract[0]+'/'+year[0]) != 'Invalid Date')
  {
    alert('valid');
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    alert('Invalid date of birth');
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtDOB" />
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="validate()" />
```

Comment: And what about day and month?

Comment: when i enter 13-13-1995, the alert message was valid, it is not correct

Comment: Last script is just for your format :)