# Check if entered date is valid in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON data containing dates (in mm/dd/yyyy format) which I am converting to `Date` object using the `Date` constructor like `new Date(year, month, day)`. I want to return the date object only if the date string is valid. For e.g., for the string '12/08/1992', I should get `Tue Dec 08 1992` as expected. But if I pass an invalid date like '15/08/1992' by doing `new Date(1992, 14, 8)` (month is always `n-1` for the `Date` constructor), I get 'Mon Mar 08 1993', which is not as expected.

Is it possible to check somehow that the entered date is invalid? 
I can't use any libraries for this.

Comment: Yes it is.  What have you tried so far? What research have you done?

Comment: @cale_b: I couldn't find an answer to this on SO.

Comment: Did you check-out https://momentjs.com ?

Comment: @Deepal: I don't want to use any libraries

Comment: _Can't_ and _want_ are entirely different - I don't usually recommend libraries, but when I do, it's momentjs.

Answer (score 0):

You can always implement your custom [date validator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6178341/5749570). Keep it simple if you don't want to use any libraries.

Answer (score 0):

```
0?[1-9] => 0...9
|  => optional
1[012] => 10..12 
[\/] => / (MM/DD/YYYY)
[12][0-9] => 10 ..... 29
3[01] => 30...31
d{4} => any with length 4 (0000...9999)
```

```js
var regex = /^(0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/]\d{4}$/;

console.log(regex.test(`12/08/1992`));

console.log(regex.test(`15/08/1992`));
```

Comment: This seems to work, but can you explain that regex a bit?

Comment: @maverick Updated.

Comment: Code-only answers are not useful, especially in this case.  Break it down.  Explain what you did, what it does, why it works.

Comment: @NishantDixit: This does not work in all cases. `console.log(regex.test(`11/31/1992`))` gives `true`, even though November has only 30 days.

Comment: Here I used regex for validate general format of Date, I did not consider above use case in this regex I think this is not possible to handle this use case using regex from my knowledge.

Comment: You can manually handle this use case but code will go lengthy