# How to validate varchar for date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, date-format, varchar

I would like to enquire if I could write a JavaScript that is to verify a varchar field so that it must fit this format `YYYY/MM/DD`?
My page is coded in ASP classic.

```
field :trdate varchar
```

On the page, it was indicated with a remark yyyy/mm/dd. See attached.

[image: varchar date field]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate date with format "mm/dd/yyyy" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177975/how-to-validate-date-with-format-mm-dd-yyyy-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Use a Regex pattern the following pattern covers that format and some variations

`/^((0[1-9]|1[012]|[1-9])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]|[1-9])[- /.](19|20)\d\d|(19|20)\d\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012]|[1-9])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]|[1-9]))$/`

Comment: Hi, how can i add above code into asp page?  <input type="Text" id="TrDate" name="TrDate" maxlength="20" size="20"  value="<%=TrDate%>"> (YYYY/MM/DD)