# How to check validation input date field

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller

I created a mask for input date field, but when someone type yearFrom in this format dd.mm.yyyy(28.45.2020), so I need when user switch to another field yearTo it need to showed him an error on input field yearFrom (Your date format is wrong) or something else.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  Year_from
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.yfrom, new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = "10", minlength="4" })
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  Year_to 
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.yto, new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = "10", minlength = "4" })
</div>
```

[image: This is picture of my two fields]

My js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#yfrom').mask('00.00.0000');
    $('#yto').mask('00.00.0000');
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems it cannot be done easily without writing a custom funciton to handle your date format or using a third-party library like [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com). [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177975/how-to-validate-date-with-format-mm-dd-yyyy-in-javascript) should help you write a proper function to handle your date format if you want it that way.

However I would opt for the use of a library since parsing the date by hand is quite cumbersome. With Moment.js you will be able to write something like `moment(dateFromUser, 'DD.MM.YYYY', true).isValid()` to check if the date provided by the user is fine.