# Check date format in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I would like to check if the date format is (dd/mm/yyyy) before the post is made in a JavaScript (jQuery).

How could I achieve that?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/276622/9885573

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a regex:

```
/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/.test(str)
```

Of course this will not check for a valid date, but in that case you can always let your server-side code throw an error. If you want more client-side validation have a look at [Javascript: how to validate dates in format MM-DD-YYYY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276479/javascript-how-to-validate-dates-in-format-mm-dd-yyyy); it is easy to adapt to your format.

Comment: Thanks it's working. I knew that regex could help but... damn that regex is hard to understand :P

Comment: Oops, just fixed it - looks like nobody who upvoted it noticed that I forgot to escape the slashes. The regex is pretty easy btw: `^$` mark the start/end of the string, `\d` is a digit, `{2}` means that you want exactly two occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

i think that would be very difficult, considering the ambiguity for cases where the date is less than equal to 12