# How to validate date for MM/YY in javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, html, validation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Formatting a date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

I have a form having lots of fields and all are validate through Java-script and one of them is for date.

```
<td>Credit Card Expiration Date</td><td>:<input class="input" type="text" name="CC_expiration_date" id="CC_expiration_date"><p>(MM/YY)</p></td>
```

Now I want that the user must enter the date in (MM/YY) format. How could I validate this using JavaScript?

I tried to make a regular expression:

```
/^(\d{2})[-\/](\d{2})[-\/](\d{4})$/.exec(date);
```

... but *didnt work*.

Comment: Have you tried regular expressions?

Comment: i tried to make a regular expression  /^(\d{2})[-\/](\d{2})[-\/](\d{4})$/.exec(date); but didnt work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this simple function.

```
function validDate(dValue) {
  var result = false;
  dValue = dValue.split('/');
  var pattern = /^\d{2}$/;

  if (dValue[0] < 1 || dValue[0] > 12)
      result = true;

  if (!pattern.test(dValue[0]) || !pattern.test(dValue[1]))
      result = true;

  if (dValue[2])
      result = true;

  if (result) alert("Please enter a valid date in MM/YY format.");
}
```

Comment: @viany ,can you please change the regular expression coz it doesn't give error if i type 12/12/2012

Comment: @HarshalMahajan As your question says you want to validate only MM/YY format. if you want to validate it for DD/MM/YYYY, you can use same answer with some formating.

Comment: actually i want that the user should enter the date like 12/12 not like 12/12/2012,and if he does than there should error MSG.you answer works fine for 12/12 but it doesn't validate for 12/12/2012

Comment: @HarshalMahajan Ok. updated accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a regular expression;

```
var s = "11/12";
/^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/\d{2}$/.test(s);
```

The first part, `(0[1-9]|1[0-2])`, validates the month part, i.e., that the value is in the range `01-12`. The second part, `\d{2}` validates the two-digit year.

Comment: it gives error msg while i entering the valid date 12/12

Comment: Are you sure the string is exactly `12/12`. Try `/^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/\d{2}$/.test("12/12")`. It returns `true`.

Comment: still not working ,not giving any error on ri8 or wrong value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

For `DD-MM-YYYY` ==> `var dateReg = /^\d{2}[./-]\d{2}[./-]\d{4}$/`

For `MM-YY` ==> `var dateReg = /^\d{2}[./-]\d{2}$/`

Know about regex.. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html

More Details [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276479/javascript-how-to-validate-dates-in-format-mm-dd-yyyy)

Comment: it wont validate if month is greater than 12. fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = "09/11"
var pattern = /^(0[1-9]|1[012])\/\d{2}$/
pattern.test(d)
```

Comment: it gives error msg while i entering the valid date 12/12

Comment: It works http://jsfiddle.net/TqwVb/