# Regex For Date validation in Javascript pointing error

Tags: javascript, regex, date

I am using the following regex for my date to validate in dd.mm.yyyy format. But any date containing 19 is not accepting, such as 19.10.2015,  19.09.2015

```
 var rgexp = /(^(((0[1-9]|[12][0-8])[.](0[1-9]|1[012]))|((29|30|31)[.](0[13578]|1[02]))|((29|30)[.](0[4,6,9]|11)))[.](19|[2-9][0-9])\d\d$)|(^29[.]02[.](19|[2-9][0-9])(00|04|08|12|16|20|24|28|32|36|40|44|48|52|56|60|64|68|72|76|80|84|88|92|96)$)/;
```

I did not find the problem. Can any body help me.

Comment: don't use regex for validating date, have you thought about leap year?

Comment: Consider http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177975/how-to-validate-date-with-format-mm-dd-yyyy-in-javascript and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276479/javascript-how-to-validate-dates-in-format-mm-dd-yyyy

Comment: Maybe that's because you used `[12][0-8]` in the `dd` part???

Comment: @LiYinKong—it allows for most leap years, not those evenly divisible by 400 though.

Comment: @ bergi : Maybe that's because you used [12][0-8] in the dd part. Changed it to  [12][0-9], not worked.