# jQuery Validation form, highlighting invalid inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have this form created in order to get a campaign name, starting/finishing date and a radio buttons to be selected.

```
<form:form id="submitCreateCampaignForm" action="createCampaign02" method="post" commandName="campaignModel">
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 140px;" >Campaign Name:</td>
            <td style="width: 300px;" colspan="4"><form:input path="campaignName" style="width:84%" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Campaign Duration:</td>
            <td colspan="1"><form:input type="text" path="fromDate" class="date-picker" /></td>
            <td colspan="1"><form:input type="text" path="toDate" class="date-picker" /></td>
            <td style="width: 250px"></td>
            <td style="width:250px"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Campaign Type:</td>
             <td colspan="2"><form:radiobuttons path="campaignType" items="${campaignTypeList}" /></td>
             <td>
                 <button class="yellowButton"id="submitCreateCampaignButton">NEXT: CHARACTERISTICS</button>
             </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

I want to assure that the name is inserted (without any length check), the dates are correctly selected in `dd/mm/yyyy` format and one of the radio buttons is selected. If any error exists I want it's box to be bordered red.

I want to check these once the user clicks on the submit button.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submitCreateCampaignButton").click( function(){
        $( "#submitCreateCampaignForm" ).submit();
    });
});
```

In order to check all the requirements mentioned above I tried different types of the validators but no success yet.

Can anyone suggest a good solution?

Comment: are you talking about jquery plugin for validation or want custom validation using jqeury and javascript?

Comment: Create your own validator,

Comment: You can use REGEX pattern to validate the form data at the time of click of submit button. Check this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN being new to jquery, That's the problem that I don't know which one to use? which one is better due to the fact that I have other forms which I should do the same verifications.

Comment: @ShekharPankaj I don't know how. and which method to use

Comment: @WisdmLabs Thanks for your suggestion, I hope it would help me :)

Comment: That is not HTML you know? Looks like Spring, or some other framework, stuff. I think you should post the resulting HTML instead (resulting page source). JQuery works on that, not on spring code.

Comment: @FrancescoMM yes, it's spring framework. ok, I will post the page source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reach the various inputs with jQuery, using selectors like input[name=campaignName]

See example and fiddle below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submitCreateCampaignForm").submit(function(e) {

    var $form = $(this);
    var errors = 0;

    var campaignName=$form.find("input[name=campaignName]").val()

    if (!errors && campaignName == "") {
      alert("nono, campaignType empty");
      errors++;
    }

    var fromDate=$form.find("input[name=fromDate]").val()

    if (!errors && fromDate == "" ) {
      alert("nono, fromDate empty");
      errors++;
    }
    if (!errors && !isValidDate(fromDate)) {
      alert("nono, fromDate "+fromDate+" not a valid date");
      errors++;
    }

    // ...

    if (errors) e.preventDefault();
  });
});

// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636536/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-an-integer-in-javascript/14794066#14794066

function isInt(value) {
  if (isNaN(value)) return false;
  var f=parseFloat(value);
  return f==(f|0);
}

// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276479/javascript-how-to-validate-dates-in-format-mm-dd-yyyy

function isValidDate(date) {
    var matches = /^(\d{2})[-\/](\d{2})[-\/](\d{4})$/.exec(date);
    if (matches == null) return false;
    var d = matches[2];
    var m = matches[1] - 1;
    var y = matches[3];

    if(y>2100 || y<1900) return false; // accept only recent & not too far years

    var composedDate = new Date(y, m, d);
    return composedDate.getDate() == d &&
            composedDate.getMonth() == m &&
            composedDate.getFullYear() == y;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ukfw3xo9/15/

This only tests two field for being not empty, a valid date, but you can test whatever you want with simple js

The `!errors &&` in front of the tests is just to alert only for the first error, not to show all errors at once (means "if you have not already reported an error and ...").

**UPDATE**

Set red fields:

https://jsfiddle.net/ukfw3xo9/16/

*CSS:*

```
.red {background-color:red;}
```

*or (border only)*

```
.red {border:1px solid red;}
```

*JAVASCRIPT:*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submitCreateCampaignForm").submit(function(e) {

    var $form = $(this);
    var errors = 0;

        $form.find("input").removeClass("red");
    var campaignName=$form.find("input[name=campaignName]").val()

    if (!errors && campaignName == "") {
      $form.find("input[name=campaignName]").addClass("red");
      errors++;
    }

    var fromDate=$form.find("input[name=fromDate]").val()

    if (!errors && fromDate == "" ) {
      $form.find("input[name=fromDate]").addClass("red");
      errors++;
    }
    if (!errors && !isValidDate(fromDate)) {
      $form.find("input[name=fromDate]").addClass("red");
      errors++;
    }

    // ...

    if (errors) e.preventDefault();
  });
});

// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636536/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-an-integer-in-javascript/14794066#14794066

function isInt(value) {
  if (isNaN(value)) return false;
  var f=parseFloat(value);
  return f==(f|0);
}

// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276479/javascript-how-to-validate-dates-in-format-mm-dd-yyyy
function isValidDate(date) {
    var matches = /^(\d{2})[-\/](\d{2})[-\/](\d{4})$/.exec(date);
    if (matches == null) return false;
    var d = matches[2];
    var m = matches[1] - 1;
    var y = matches[3];

    if(y>2100 || y<1900) return false; // accept only recent & not too far years

    var composedDate = new Date(y, m, d);
    return composedDate.getDate() == d &&
            composedDate.getMonth() == m &&
            composedDate.getFullYear() == y;
}
```

You can now remove all the "!errors && " (all cells will become red not only the first one).

This code is a bit ugly, just to show the concept, a cleaner way is to get the inputs only once:

```
var $fromDateInput=$form.find("input[name=fromDate]");
var fromDateValue=$fromDateInput.val();

if (fromDateValue == "" ) {
    $fromDateInput.addClass("red");
    errors++;
}
```

Comment: YOU ARE THE BESSST ! thanks resolved. Now I should replace pop-up errors with red border boxes.

Comment: @reshad Like `$form.find("input[name=fromDate]").addClass("red");` and define `.red {border:1px solid red;}` in css file. But first clear all reds at submit with `$form.find("input").removeClass("red");` (remove from all inputs). I'll update the answer

Comment: Thanks again for your useful help.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a tag named 'required', and set the rigth type of field, like type 'email' when the field is an email. If the type is 'text' the browser will only check if the input is populated.

Why do you set the name of input as 'form:input', instead of just 'input'?

And a example of input with the required tag

```
<form>
    <input type='text' name='test' required />
    <input type='email' name='email' required /> <!-- will check if is an email -->
    <input type='number' name='telephone' required /> <!-- will check if is an number -->
    <input type='submit'/>
</form>
```

Read more about html5 fields, and u will need jquery validate only for some cases.

And remember, you need to re-validate on server, due to some type of hack on front.

Comment: the problem is that required does not work in safari.