# Regex to validate date yyyy-mm-dd while typing (on keyup)

Tags: regex

I need to validade date *yyyy-mm-dd* on user keyup.

I'm currently at validating *yyyy-mm* with this Regex

```
^\d{0,4}$|^\d{4}[-]$|^\d{4}[-](0?[0-9]|1[012])$
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/luisteixeira/fnp8tc5s/)

But I need validade others part of date. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and clarify exactly what it is you don't understand?

Comment: A regular expression can't validate anything more than four digits, hyphen, two digits, hyphen, two digits. It can't determine whether the year is in a reasonable range, whether the month is in the range 01 through 12, or whether the date is in the month-length-dependent range of 01 to 28, 29, 30, or 31.

Comment: Your current more looks like it does *yyyy-mm* and not *yyyy-dd*

Comment: Yes ,but i need yyy-mm-dd

Comment: @Steve You could absolutely enumerate the valid dates to make sure the month is between 01 and 12 and even to make sure the day of month is in an expected range ... even for leap years if you like typing.

Comment: Try [`^\d{0,4}$|^\d{4}-0?$|^\d{4}-(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])(?:-(?:0?[1-9]?|[12]\d|3[01])?)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/jB9lZ7/2). You want to validate while typing right?

Comment: Is this , thank you @bobble

Comment: welcome, just modified it a bit ([version 2](https://regex101.com/r/jB9lZ7/2)).

Comment: @triplee, I see you are correct. My skills have been corrupted by too much Windows. However the expression by *bobble bubble* still doesn't understand month length; it appears that it will accept 2016-04-31 or 2015-02-29, for example.

Comment: @Steve Possible duplicate of [Regular Expression | Leap Years and More](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647893/regular-expression-leap-years-and-more)

Comment: @Steve My regex is not to validate a full date but to check if the input characters while typed match the *yyyy-mm-dd* pattern (what was asked). Updated my answer to make it more clear : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Explanation*: Vague checking input **while typing** if it matches the desired format `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Modified your current regex a bit and added the `dd` part so it becomes

```
^\d{0,4}$|^\d{4}-0?$|^\d{4}-(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])(?:-(?:0?[1-9]?|[12]\d|3[01])?)?$
```

- `(?:` opens a [non capture group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group) for alternation
- `0?[1-9]?` optional 1-9 with preceding 0 or zero
- `[12]\d` days 10-29
- `3[01]` days 30 and 31

[See the demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jB9lZ7/3)

[image]

---

For `dd-mm-yyyy` try [this variant](https://regex101.com/r/5bXhkG/1):

```
^0?$|^(?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(?:-(?:(?:0$|0?[1-9]|1[012]?)(?:-\d{0,4})?)?)?$
```

---

Or for `mm-dd-yyyy` [that one](https://regex101.com/r/BNMvy3/1):

```
^0?$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1[012]?)(?:-(?:(?:0$|0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(?:-\d{0,4})?)?)?$
```

---

**This does not actually validate a date** (leap years/28-31 days). Just loose checks input while typing, you can probably make it shorter. As follows an example with the `yyyy-mm-dd` pattern.

```js
$("#date").on("keyup", function()
{
    let valid = /^\d{0,4}$|^\d{4}-0?$|^\d{4}-(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])(?:-(?:0?[1-9]?|[12]\d|3[01])?)?$/.test(this.value), input = this.value;
    
    if(!valid) {
        this.value = input.substring(0, input.length - 1);
        this.style.backgroundColor = '#EEA39C';
    }
    setTimeout(() => { this.style.backgroundColor = '#88DD85'; }, 700);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="date" style="font-size: 20px" maxlength="10" type="text" />
```

**To validate the full** date when typed/submitted [see this answer of @PhiLho](https://stackoverflow.com/a/276622/5527985) and rearrange it to the desired format, e.g. for `yyyy-mm-dd`

```js
function isValidDate(date)
{
    var matches = /^(\d{4})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})$/.exec(date);
    if (matches == null) return false;
    var y = matches[1];
    var m = matches[2] - 1;
    var d = matches[3];
    var composedDate = new Date(y, m, d);
    return composedDate.getDate() == d &&
            composedDate.getMonth() == m &&
            composedDate.getFullYear() == y;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="date" style="font-size: 17px" value="2016-03-16">
<button onclick="alert(
  isValidDate(getElementById('date').value)
);" style="font-size: 17px">check date</button>
```

Comment: `2016-04-31` and `2016-02-31` is valid in your regex, which is wrong.

Comment: @AhsanulHaque Tried to clarify. It's just a loose check based on OP's regex while typing. It does not really validate a date. The full string should finally be checked if it is a valid date.

Comment: @bobblebubble using the regex you shared here i was trying out for `dd-mm-yyyy` and `mm-dd-yyyy` formats, the first two digits on keypress its not validating to true, i am sure i missing out something silly here,. can please have a look and help me here.. `^(?:(?:0?[1-9]?|[12]\d|3[01])?)(?:-(?:0?[0-9]|1[012])?)(?:-(?:\d{0,4}|\d{4})?)?$`

Comment: @ashwathmabiyan Na, it needs refactoring. Just had some quick tries... [this one for `dd-mm-yyyy`](https://regex101.com/r/5bXhkG/1) and [another one for `mm-dd-yyyy`](https://regex101.com/r/BNMvy3/1)

Answer (score 2):

This regex is a bit complex, but check the whole Gregorian rule.

```
 regExp = "(((\d{2}(([13579][26])|([2468][480])|(0[48])))|(([13579][26])|([02468][480]))00)-02-29)|(\d{4}-((?:(0[13578]|1[02])-([0-2]\d|3[0-1]))|(?:(0[469]|11)-([0-2]\d|30))|(?:02-([0-1]\d|2[0-8]))))"
```

Comment: Your sulution validate full date, I need validate on user type a date. See link i add in my post.

Comment: @Ahsanul Haque, does that check the whole Gregorian rule, or just the Julian? Even just the latter is quite impressive; one would hope that it's OK to incorrectly approve three days per four centuries. (A further complication for that question is that the Gregorian rule is not supposed to be used on dates before 1582, but that's not worth the bother for most purposes.)

Comment: @Steve, yes, it does check the whole Gregorian rule.

Comment: @Ahsanul Haque, wow, that's impressive. The complexity of the expression makes it difficult to tell without diagramming it out on paper (or asking). That suggests that a regular expression is the wrong tool for the job, unless the question is posed as a regular expression challenge, as opposed to a question of the best tool for the task.

Comment: (The tool for the task is to pass the input to a date parse function, as the link in @tripleee 's comment advises.)

Answer (score 0):

```
var regExp = /^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})$/

regExp.test(value);
```

Comment: I had the same idea, but the example in the question also validates for partial availability.

Comment: I need validate month and day . with your suggestion i could not.

Comment: Your regex will match `0002-67-99`.

Comment: Adding an explanation of how this RegEx answers the question will improve your answer for future visitors.